# SQL query to get all products, categories and meta data woocommerce/wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm stuck trying to create a query that returns me the parameters:

ID, post_title, post_content, category, ID_category, SKU, name, stock, price

At this moment I have this:

```
SELECT 
 p.ID,
 p.post_title,
 `post_content`,
 `post_excerpt`,
 t.name AS product_category,
 t.slug AS product_slug,
 tt.term_taxonomy_id AS tt_term_taxonomia,
 tr.term_taxonomy_id AS tr_term_taxonomia,
 MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price,
 MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_regular_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as regular_price,
 MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sale_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sale_price,
 MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sku' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sku 

 FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID)
 LEFT JOIN   wp_term_relationships AS tr ON ( tr.object_id = p.ID )
 LEFT JOIN   wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON ( tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tr.object_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
 LEFT JOIN   wp_terms AS t ON ( t.term_id = tt.term_id )
 WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_content <> ''
 GROUP BY p.ID,p.post_title
```

And it is giving me correctly the products and the metadata but it is  very difficult for me to get the category ID and the category name in this query and I haven't been able to find information on the net.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the database model -- where exactly is a column called Category ID? https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description -- Which columns do you want?

Comment: Hi @Hogan, thanks for your reply. All product information is stored on Wordpress database as posts. https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: Well, all term/taxonomy information would be in `wp_terms` and possibly also `wp_term_taxonomy` and `wp_term_relationships`. What is your reasoning for this query? There is probably a better way than a pure SQL query. WordPress has it's own functions (like `get_posts()`) and WooCommerce has an [API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)

Answer (score 7):

You had `object_id` joining to `term_taxonomy_id` which made no sense.

Here is how I think it should be -- *caveat: I've never queried a wp database and was just going by the documentation.*

```
SELECT 
  p.ID,
  p.post_title,
  `post_content`,
  `post_excerpt`,
  t.name AS product_category,
  t.term_id AS product_id,
  t.slug AS product_slug,
  tt.term_taxonomy_id AS tt_term_taxonomia,
  tr.term_taxonomy_id AS tr_term_taxonomia,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_regular_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as regular_price,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sale_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sale_price,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sku' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sku 
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_content <> ''
GROUP BY p.ID,p.post_title
```

Comment: it is showing the same product category for all products :(

Comment: can't help you unless you show me some real sample data and expected results.

Comment: @superTramp the reason why you are getting the same product category is because it is the parent category. You can modify JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' JOIN tt.parent != 0 AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id in order to get the lowest product category in terms hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW

I started on the same thing myself.  And I wanted to add product category and Google led me here.

The following code also shows the variation products, not only the post/product main/root for the variations:

```
SELECT 
post_id,
t.name AS product_category,
IF(p.post_parent = 0, p.ID, p.post_parent) AS post_parent,
(SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE id = pm.post_id) AS title,
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_price" LIMIT 1) AS price, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_regular_price" LIMIT 1) AS "regular price", 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_stock" LIMIT 1) AS stock, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_stock_status" LIMIT 1) AS "stock status", 
IFNULL((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_sku" LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_custom_field" LIMIT 1)) as SKU,
IFNULL(SUBSTR( (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_product_attributes" LIMIT 1),
    INSTR((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_product_attributes" LIMIT 1), "is_variation")+16,1),1) AS "variation"

FROM `wp_postmeta` AS pm
JOIN wp_posts AS p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = IF(p.post_parent = 0, p.ID, p.post_parent)
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id

WHERE meta_key in ("_product_version")
AND p.post_status in ("publish")
AND IFNULL(SUBSTR((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_product_attributes" LIMIT 1),
INSTR((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = "_product_attributes" LIMIT 1), "is_variation")+16,1),0)=0
```